# Change the color and content in cell (static) by clicking and keep changes after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql, html-table

I am trying to make a status overview site for my work. I would like to make it like a table and where you click the cell then the cell will change between 3 options. I made an example here but I would like to have everything in one row.

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</td>
      <th>Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Martin</td>
    <td bgcolor="green">Option 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Martin</td>
    <td bgcolor="red">Option 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Martin</td>
    <td bgcolor="orange">Option 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then I would like the page to save the changes. Do I need SQL or can I run some javascript or something?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Search for guides on using local storage

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without using any server side database. you can use sessionStorage or localStorage (html5) it's easy. take a look at:

http://zenorocha.com/html5-local-storage/
or
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

if you're not able to get it by yourself, come back again and tell your new troubble

Answer (score 0):

also, you can use cookies

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Set your td index and color,
and when page is reloaded - read all available cookies